# MDS AppLaud Eclipse PhoneGap plugin directory error

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am trying to create and a new android project with eclipse using MDS AppLaud Phonegap plugin. I have install both android ADT and the PhoneGap plugin.

The current version of PhoneGap the plugin provide is 1.9.0 however i want to use PhoneGap 2.9.0. so I chose "enter path to installed PhoneGap" I then browse to my downloaded version of PhoneGap folder and selected the "lib" folder that contains all the various folders for mobile platforms. However phonegap eclipse plugin says

" Invalid phonegap-android location. If it's from github,it should have a framework and example subdirectory.If it's from www.phonegap.com Download, it should have an Android subdirectory"

when I changed the "android" folder name to "Android" now it says

"Invalid phonegap-android location: C:\wamp\sdk\phonegap\lib/Android must include a example directory, phonegap{version}.js and phonegap{version}.jar"

inside the android folder i only have cordova.js and cordova-2.9.0.jar. I have tried different ways but it is still not working.

I will be glad if anyone can help me solve this problem. it is really giving me a real head-knock.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just linked it to the main folder not the lib folder and it worked